# float miscalculation when int32_t variable is divided by 10

Tags: float, convert

i want to ask, how to get correct float value from uint32_t or long variable is devided by 10??

```
long var3 = 1139399025;
int a = 3;
int b = 10;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println((float)a/b,2);
  Serial.println((float)var3/b,2);
}
void loop() {
}
```

result

```
0.3
113939904.00
```

it give 113939904.00 instead of 113939902.50, plase how to fix that?

Comment: what is the value of var3 when it is converted to float?

Comment: long var3 = 1139399025;

Comment: Floats have only limited precision see: https://cdn.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/float/ . You get better precision using a double but only on a 32 bit Arduino (Due etc.). However there will still be some loss of precision.

Comment: I use arduino mega 2560

Answer (score 2):

1139399025 is not a floating point number: the largest odd integer that
can be exactly represented as a `float` is
2<sup>24</sup> − 1 = 16777215. Then, when `var3` is
cast to `float`, it gets rounded to the closest float, which
is 1139399040. This is quite a small error, especially considering
that, in this range, only multiples of 128 can be exactly
represented as floats.

Dividing 1139399040 by 10 gives 113939904, which happens to be a float.
The floating point division gives then the *exact* result, which is what
gets printed. Indeed, floating point operations do not always give
inexact results: sometimes they are exact. However, unless you know what
you are doing, exact results only happen by luck. In general, expect
each floating point operation to make a *relative* rounding error in the
range of 10<sup>−7</sup>.

A highly recommended read: [What Every Programmer Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

**Edit**: If you want to print the value of an integer divided by 10,
you can divide the number using [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). Print the
quotient, then the decimal point, then the remainder:

```cpp
Serial.print(var3 / 10);  // quotient
Serial.print('.');
Serial.println(var3 % 10);  // remainder
```

As these are all integer operations, there is no rounding error
involved. Obviously this trick doesn't work for arbitrary divisors.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: @mukhlas: Do not use floats.

Comment: @mukhlas Or use `double` that provide more significant digits, for this specific case. But in any case you need to understand floating-point, as Edgar suggested.

Comment: @thebusybee: The AVR microcontrollers (or rather, their port of GCC) do not support double precision floats: their `double` type is implemented as float32, just like `float`.

Comment: Oh, really? Well, then, no luck. :-(

Comment: Thanks you all :)